# How to add an image of a Silverlight UiElement to Word Document

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, ms-word, writeablebitmap, uielement

I want to add an image of a certain `DataGrid` in silverlight to a word Document.

I've created a `WriteableBitmap` of the `DataGrid` but I can't find how to copy this image to the word document.

It doesn't have to be a `WriteableImage`. Any solution that works is fine with me.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you creating your word document? Are you asking how to do this from the clipboard?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible as of Silverlight 5.

> In Silverlight 5, access to clipboard information is limited to
>   Unicode text access. This differs from the WPF implementation of
>   Clipboard, which enables access to other specific types (for example,
>   streams or images) or to data objects.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).